# expressionengine does not display template page when logged out

Tags: templates, login, ee, logout

in my project i have a products list page and when you click on each product you see the single project page, i have this structure in many projects and working fine, but in this project the single product page displays only when i'm logged in, very weird. i checked admin panel and couldn't find any option for template login or logout permission.
my project list url is `mysite.com/projects` and my single project page is `mysite.com/project/project-1`

i don't know what's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check your Template **Access** permissions? These are documented in detail here : https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/templates/edit_template.html#access

Also, perhaps you can confirm what version of EE you are running?

Finally, I note from your URL's you are using Freindly URL's, not a problem but can you confirm your routing settings for the single product pages? Also, the state of your Strict URL settings in EE please?

Comment: thanks Blatant, i changed template access permissions for template view to "yes" and it worked, thanks. by the way ee version is 2.8.1 and strict url is set to "No" ;)

Comment: Glad your sorted :) Not often the first answer is the right one!